# Must declare the scalar varialble

Tags: mysql, sql, select, parameters, where-clause

I am using this simple code to pivot some column.

But I can't make it work due to that error.

```
DECLARE @IO_dy AS VARCHAR(100) = '>9C604-M'
DECLARE @style_dy AS VARCHAR (100) = 'S1415MBS06'
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @con AS VARCHAR(8000)
SET @con = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Size_id) 
                  FROM iPLEXSTY_SIQ 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Po_no,a.Article_id,a.Season_id,a.Customer_id,a.Destn_id,b.planned_dt, (c.Description + c.Resource_id) AS comb_size,a.Qty,a.Size_id
    from iPLEXSTY_SIQ a
    INNER JOIN iPLEX_BULK_PO_DET b on b.upload_batch_id = a.Batch_id  
    INNER JOIN iPLEXCOLORS c on c.Seq_no = a.Seq_no 
    WHERE IO_no = @IO_dy AND Style_id = @style_dy       //ERROR HERE
    GROUP BY a.Po_no,a.Article_id,a.Season_id,a.Customer_id,a.Destn_id,b.planned_dt,(c.Description + c.Resource_id),a.Qty,A.Size_id
) as s

PIVOT
(
    SUM(Qty)
    FOR Size_id IN (' +@con+ ')
)AS pvt'    

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: "But I can't make it work due to that error." - What error exactly?

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable @IO_dy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addition to another answer 
just single quotes to the variable names used in the query

```
DECLARE @IO_dy AS VARCHAR(100) = '>9C604-M'
DECLARE @style_dy AS VARCHAR (100) = 'S1415MBS06'
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @con AS VARCHAR(8000)
SET @con = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Size_id) 
                  FROM iPLEXSTY_SIQ 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Po_no,a.Article_id,a.Season_id,a.Customer_id,a.Destn_id,b.planned_dt, (c.Description + c.Resource_id) AS comb_size,a.Qty,a.Size_id
    from iPLEXSTY_SIQ a
    INNER JOIN iPLEX_BULK_PO_DET b on b.upload_batch_id = a.Batch_id  
    INNER JOIN iPLEXCOLORS c on c.Seq_no = a.Seq_no 
    WHERE IO_no = '''+@IO_dy+''' AND Style_id = '''+@style_dy+'''       //ERROR HERE
    GROUP BY a.Po_no,a.Article_id,a.Season_id,a.Customer_id,a.Destn_id,b.planned_dt,(c.Description + c.Resource_id),a.Qty,A.Size_id
) as s

PIVOT
(
    SUM(Qty)
    FOR Size_id IN (' +@con+ ')
)AS pvt'    

EXEC(@query)
```

and also as another answer explains to set values to varchar using `default` keyword

Comment: what is exact value of `@IO_dy`  is it `>9C604-M` or `9C604-M`

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare and initialize value of variable using "=". So instead of:

```
DECLARE @IO_dy AS VARCHAR(100) = '>9C604-M'
```

Use

```
 DECLARE @IO_dy AS VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '>9C604-M'
                                ^^^^^^^
```

See this for [syntax](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/variables-in-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: DECLARE @IO_dy AS VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '>9C604-M'

I use this but have this error 'Incorrect syntax near DEFAULT'